# How to connect deployed Smart contract in java

Tags: blockchain, java

im completely new with blockchain,

My Front end Team have successfully communicated the smart contract and able to call the method that is available in Smart contract, so the thing is smart contract deployed, now i have to integrate the same using java. i have gone through this document https://docs.web3j.io/4.10.0/getting_started/deploy_interact_smart_contracts/, but nothing helps.. not sure how to proceed. any help could be helpfull here

Comment: Thank you for coming here. This forum is not good for tutoring. Please edit the question to include specific errors or questions for which you want to have the answer. Otherwise the answer is "learn and follow the documentation like other Java programmers have done before."

Comment: It's easy to miss, but there is a snippet on the page you linked for deployment - you need to generate a wrapper for a compiled contract, and then call `deploy` on it. Maybe try ctrl-f searching the word "deploy" on the page if you aren't finding it.

Comment: Adding it for future reference.. yes we can generate wrapper to interact with smart contract. 

below are the steps:   

1. install web3j
2. install solc complier 
3. run the command to generate .abi and .bin file : solcjs Greeting.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o ./ 
4. run the command to generate wrapper class:  web3j generate solidity -b Greeting.bin -a Greeting.abi -o location in which you wanted the wrappers classes to be generate 
5. once you have generate then you can copy and paste in your workspace to interact

Comment: Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService(web3Url));  Credentials dummyCredentials = Credentials.create(Keys.createEcKeyPair()); DefaultGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider(); contractGasProvider.getGasPrice(contractAddress);Greetings contractInstance=Greetings.load(contractAddress, web3, dummyCredentials, contractGasProvider);
  RemoteFunctionCall<BigInteger> remoteFunctionCallSingleValue=contractInstance.test(fromAddress, toAddress); // this is we have to call the smart contract methodBigInteger test= remoteFunctionCallSingleValue.send();